# how to insert a selection element in html form using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I must insert a  element in an html file where I am using bootstrap. I have tried the following:

```
<form role="form" action="mailto:sm.ayman10@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="objectinput"><h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Objet</h4></label>
        <select class="form-control" type="object" id="objectinput">
            <option value="info">Demande d'information</option>
            <option value="order">Commande</option>
            <option value="sans" selected><span style="color:#B29999;">Selectionez l'objet de votre requ&ecirc;te</span>  </option>
        </select>
    </div>                      
</form>
```

Everything is working fine except for one thing: the color of the text in the selection. so that it looks like a placeholder for the "selected" item, but I failed. It is displaying in black :/  can anyone tell me how to change the color of the text inside  tag !

Comment: Define `selection element`.

Comment: the <select> tag . the user must choose from three options: option1, option2, and option3. I want to use the text in option 3 as a placeholder because the placeholder attribute does not work :/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the color of the text in the select input, do this:

```
#objectinput {
  color: red;
}
```

If you want option 3 to be pre-selected, do this:

```
<option value="sans" selected>Selectionez l'objet de votre requête  </option>
```

[Working Example](http://www.bootply.com/120045)

**UPDATE**

If you want just to target the third option use this (nth-child(3) didn't work for me..):

```
#objectinput option + option + option
{
  color: red;
}
```

if you just want to target the selected option, use this:

```
#objectinput option:checked
{
  color: red;
}
```

[Working Example](http://www.bootply.com/120159)

Comment: I know option 3 is preselected , what I want is to change only the color of option 3. If I do as you tell I will change the color of all options , but I only want to change the color of the third option.